# Can't restart /etc/init.d/apache2 restart = failed

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, failed

After installing openssl ssl-cert and setting everything up as described in the tutorial, I can't restart my apache2. I get the following error:

[image]

Here is the error.log:

```
root@debian:/var/log/apache2# nano error.log
  GNU nano 2.2.4                                                  File: error.log

[Sat Dec 15 17:18:22 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 15 17:18:24 2012] [error] [client 192.168.56.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Dec 15 17:22:03 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Dec 15 17:22:08 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 15 17:22:51 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Dec 15 17:22:58 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 15 17:23:23 2012] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Sat Dec 15 17:23:24 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 15 17:26:21 2012] [error] [client 192.168.56.1] File does not exist: /var/www/index.phg
[Sat Dec 15 17:26:21 2012] [error] [client 192.168.56.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Dec 15 17:27:08 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Dec 15 17:27:10 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze14 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 15 17:27:15 2012] [error] [client 192.168.56.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Dec 15 17:30:50 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Dec 15 17:30:53 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze14 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 15 17:36:36 2012] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Sat Dec 15 17:36:37 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze14 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 15 17:37:56 2012] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Sat Dec 15 17:37:57 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze14 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 15 17:38:12 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Dec 15 17:38:14 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze14 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 15 17:39:29 2012] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Sat Dec 15 17:39:31 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze14 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 15 17:39:51 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Dec 15 17:39:52 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze14 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 15 18:47:34 2012] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Sat Dec 15 18:47:44 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze14 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 15 18:48:50 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Dec 15 18:48:52 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze14 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 15 19:00:02 2012] [error] [client 192.168.56.1] File does not exist: /var/www/oscommerce/install
[Sat Dec 15 19:00:02 2012] [error] [client 192.168.56.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Dec 15 19:00:46 2012] [error] [client 192.168.56.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Dec 15 19:00:51 2012] [error] [client 192.168.56.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Dec 15 19:00:53 2012] [error] [client 192.168.56.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Dec 15 19:00:55 2012] [error] [client 192.168.56.1] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /var/www/oscommerce/catalog/in$
[Sat Dec 15 19:00:55 2012] [error] [client 192.168.56.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Dec 15 19:00:57 2012] [error] [client 192.168.56.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Dec 15 19:01:01 2012] [error] [client 192.168.56.1] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /var/www/oscommerce/catalog/in$
[Sat Dec 15 19:01:01 2012] [error] [client 192.168.56.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Dec 15 19:01:13 2012] [error] [client 192.168.56.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Dec 15 19:04:53 2012] [error] [client 192.168.56.1] PHP Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in /var/www/oscommerce/catalog/install/includes/functions/database.php on line 98, $
[Sat Dec 15 19:04:53 2012] [error] [client 192.168.56.1] PHP Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in /var/www/oscommerce/catalog/install/includes/functions/database.php on line 98, $
[Sat Dec 15 19:04:53 2012] [error] [client 192.168.56.1] PHP Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in /var/www/oscommerce/catalog/install/includes/functions/database.php on line 98, $
[Sat Dec 15 19:04:53 2012] [error] [client 192.168.56.1] PHP Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in /var/www/oscommerce/catalog/install/includes/functions/database.php on line 98, $
[Sat Dec 15 19:04:53 2012] [error] [client 192.168.56.1] PHP Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in /var/www/oscommerce/catalog/install/includes/functions/database.php on line 98, $
```

Comment: Please provide the `default-ssl` file mentioned in that error.

Comment: I am still trying to copy the content so I can post it here. It's from my virtual box debian server. I use putty, but I can't copy/paste everything yet

Comment: @F4LLCON One way is using SCP. For example [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) to transfer the log files to your Windows PC.

Comment: My bad, I found the problem, before `<IfModule>` there was an `\`, after removing that, I got the next error saying that the path was not correct, I corrected the path and both errors are solved now. Thank you for WinSCP, I will try that out for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your `default-ssl` file. Search the document for all mentions of `ifModule` and make sure that they have matching open and close statements. Enabling syntax highlighting in your editor can help you spot errors like this better.

Comment: My bad, I found the problem, before `<IfModule>` there was an `\`, after removing that, I got the next error saying that the path was not correct, I corrected the path and both errors are solved now. Thank you for WinSCP, I will try that out for the future.